# Helping with models in DjangoREST

Tags: python, django

I am making API in Django rest and I am not sure what to do with groupID. I have just 1 model - countries. I have assigned request and response.

Request for POST is :

```
{"name": "Czech Republic","countryCode": "CZ"}
```

Response is:

```
{ "name": "Czech Republic","countryCode": "CZ","id": 123,"createdAt": "2022-08-21T11:49:39.239Z", "groupId": 123 }
```

And I am supposed to create an API for that. I am not sure what to do with groups in model.

```
class Countries(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
   countryCode = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
   createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   groupId = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)

   def __str__(self):return self.name
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: what is is qroup_id here??

Comment: if you are not sure what is group id you can easily override the save method to make  group_id = id of the model

Comment: I have added a screenshot. I though about that, but I am not sure if it makes sense. What would be the purpose of this?

Comment: @MohamedBeltagy I have tried it, but django is throwing error: Model country_API.Countries can't have more than one auto-generated field.

Comment: contact me mmk.mmk0@gmail.com